# Python Looping for Store Data

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi, temp, temperature

I want to ask about looping. This my Code I'm using Python. Please Help me to get the looping.

```
temp = 0 # temperature
valve = 0 #control temperature

while True :
  if temp = 30
    valve =+ 20
    print "temp now 30 and valve 20"
  elif temp = 40
    valve =+ 40
    print "temp now 40 and valve 40"
  else
    print "temp n and valve n"

time.sleep(5) #looping 5 second not happen i get error
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please state the inputs, desired outputs and post your errors

Comment: that's part or slice of my python code

Comment: with `if` you probably want to check equality (`==`), not assignment (`=`). `if temp == 30:`. You're also missing `:` at then end of your conditional lines. Does this code even run?

Comment: yes code is run. Thank You @JonSurrell. I Have one question again. how do looping in a python program but if a variable that has been repeated need not be repeated ?

Comment: Is it doing anything like what you expect? Shouldn't `time.sleep(5)` be inside the `while` block? Shouldn't `=+` be `+=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted code and assuming you are trying to loop indefinitely with a period of 5s and increase the valve value depending on temperature, this code runs:

```
import time

temp = 0 # temperature
valve = 0 #control temperature

while True:
    if temp == 30:
        valve += 20
    elif temp == 40:
        valve += 40
    else:
        valve = 'n' 
        temp = 'n'

    print "temp now {temp} and valve {valve}".format(temp=temp, valve=valve)
    time.sleep(5) #looping 5 second not happen i get error
```

Mistakes I could spot:

- No import of time (`import time`)
- Conditional statements in python are followed by `:`
- You were using `=` to check for equality, while the correct syntax is `==`
- Python uses indentation to keep track of code blocks, so `time.sleep(5)` should be also aligned with the if statements, so that it is part of the while loop
- (not an error), but an improvement: you can set your valve values in the conditional part of your loop and only print once at the end

Comment: thank you for youre answer. I want asked again, how do looping in a python program but if a variable that has been repeated need not be repeated ? such as break and continue . @Damian

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Is it that you want to loop over the unique values of a list?

Comment: If that's the case (looping over the unique values of a list) - just use set(list).
So, you will have something like:

for iterator in set(duplicate_list):
    # do something